# Table View doesn't reload data from Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a little problem.
So here it is:

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView (delegate and datasource set). In my ViewDidLoad i query all the data from Parse.com and store it in multiple NSMutableArrays (i initialize before adding object to them)

`viewDidLoad`:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PlacesClass"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    [titlesArray addObject:object[@"PlaceName"]];
                    [thumbnailsArray addObject:object[@"PlaceImageURL"]];      
                 }
                finishedLoading = YES;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }];
```

It's working great. It shows the data correctly in the TableView.
However, I have a sliding menu with a TableView with some categories. When you tap on one of the categories I do a query again to get all objects with a specific category, like this:

```
-(void)searchWithCategory{

AppDelegate * delegate = DELEGATE;
_categoryToSearch = delegate.categoryToSearch;

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PlacesClass"];
[query whereKey:@"Category" equalTo:_categoryToSearch];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        NSMutableArray *titlesArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *thumbnailsArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *facebookArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *twitterArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *addressArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *descriptiomArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *locationArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            [titlesArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceName"]];
            [thumbnailsArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceImageURL"]];
            [facebookArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceFacebookAddress"]];
            [twitterArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceTwitterAddress"]];
            [addressArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceAddress"]];
            [descriptiomArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceDescription"]];
            [locationArray2 addObject:object[@"PlaceLocation"]];
        }

        titlesArray = titlesArray2;
        thumbnailsArray = thumbnailsArray2;
        descriptiomArray = descriptiomArray2;
        facebookArray = facebookArray2;
        twitterArray = twitterArray2;
        addressArray = addressArray2;
        locationArray = locationArray2;

        finishedLoading = YES;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    } else 
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}];
}
```

I call this method from the sliding view controller's class when a category is selected. I NSLogged the arrays and the new data is correct. It shows the right objects from the specific category.

However the TableView doesn't reload. I run `reloadData` on the main thread and i still get no signal from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `numbersOfRowsInSection`. I am using a custom UITableViewCell. I don't know if it's related to this, but i tried with simple UITableViewCells and it's still the same issue. The TableView reloads only when displaying data for the first time.

This is how I call the `searchWithCategory` method from the sliding menu view controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      AppDelegate * delegate = DELEGATE;
      delegate.categoryToSearch = [_categoriesNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      PlacesViewController *pvc = [[PlacesViewController alloc]init];
     [pvc searchWithCategory];

}
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to solve this ? I am stucked with this for about 4 days. 
Thank you a lot for reading my question!

**EDIT: My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customCell = (PlacesTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"PlacesTableViewCell"];
    if (customCell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlacesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        customCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if(finishedLoading == YES){
        customCell.placeName.text = [titlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[thumbnailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
        customCell.thumbnail.image = image;
     }

    if(indexPath.row == titlesArray.count-1)
        finishedLoading = NO;

    return customCell;
    }
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code I see anything that results in PlacesViewController's view loaded. You need to see results on a tableview that seems to have not been loaded from xib or otherwise.

Comment: @mithleshjha My TableView is loaded from Storyboard. I didn't posted the entire ViewDidLoad. I set the delegate and datasource of the tableView. Can you explain me if there is anything else than that ? Thank you

Comment: Show your cellforrowatindexpath method..

Comment: @rptwsthi i added the cellforrowatindexpath method..

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

You are actually using `titlesArray` for populating data to `tableView`. Although I am still not very sure about the problem but I can provide you a check list, check below :

- Check if parse returning data (print parse data count after it is retrieved)
- Then check if you have initialize your array before adding data to it
- Then check if `titlesArray` have data in it (print it)
- Check if you are returning `numberOfRowInSection` from `titlesArray.count`

Try these, hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you a lot @rptwsthi, but i already did everything you said.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify your code.
In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are initializing `PlacesViewController` and then running `[pvc searchWithCategory];` 
Is implementation of searchWithCategory method in a different file?
Are the properties `titlesArray` `thumbnailsArray` etc... global variables? 
Why would you need to initialize `PlacesViewController`?

I am guessing this is an IPAD app and you are in the `splitviewcontroller` so you can see both controllers?  The `PlacesViewController` has it's own tableview?

```
[self.tableview reload]
```

that is called in `-(void)searchWithCategory`which tableView you are referring?

Comment: I am initializing "PlacesViewController" from a class called "LeftPaneViewController", which is the class of the left side panel i was talking about. From that class i am calling the method "[pvc searchWithCategory];", which belongs to "PlacesViewController". Thank you @Yan!

Comment: The properties that you listed are not global properties. I initialize "PlacesViewController" on the "LeftPaneViewController" in order to call "PlacesViewController's" method "searchWithCategory". It's not an iPad app. Yes, the PlacesViewController has it's own tableView. The tableView i am refering to is the one on the main screen (PlacesViewController)

Comment: Then which tableView you are trying to reload?